# Retrieving a few random snapshots from the same giant Firebase DB object

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database, nosql

How do I get random isolated values from an object in NodeJS? How do I know if and when the requests were fulfilled? I mean without doing this:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var obj = [];
    ref("games").child(rnd(range)).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        obj.push(snapshot.val());
    }).then(function() {
        ref("games").child(rnd(range)).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
            obj.push(snapshot.val());
        }).then(function() {
            ref("games").child(rnd(range)).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
                obj.push(snapshot.val());
            }).then(function() {
                ref("games").child(rnd(range)).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
                    obj.push(snapshot.val());
                }).then(function() {
                    ref("games").child(rnd(range)).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
                        obj.push(snapshot.val());
                    }).then(function() {
                        ref("games").child(rnd(range)).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
                            obj.push(snapshot.val());
                        }).then(function() {
                            response.end(JSON.stringify(obj));
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}).listen(8081);
```

I can't seem to get recursive code going because I'm new to this and there is so much data moving around .

Comment: `rnd(range)` returns some random key, and you're trying to successively get several values?

Comment: @qxz It returns `Math.floor(Math.random() * range)`. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing each request sequentially like that probably isn't the best way to do it; there's no reason to wait for the last one to complete before initiating the next one. The trick, of course, is knowing when the last request has completed. I usually just use a counter for this:

```
function getSomeStuff(numToGet, callback) {
  var obj = []; // accumulates the results
  var numDone = 0; // keeps track of how many of the requests have completed
  for (var n=0; n<numToGet; n++) {
    ref("games").child(rnd(range)).once("value", function(snapshot) {
      // NOTE: inside this function, n will always ==numToGet!
      obj.push(snapshot.val());
      if (++numDone == numToGet) { // if this is the last request to complete,
        callback(obj); // call the callback with the results
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then inside your `http` handler, simply:

```
getSomeStuff(6, function(obj) {
  response.end(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

Comment: I know sequential requests are bad but I was just trying to illustrate what I was trying to accomplish. Your code works beautifully! It's also blazingly fast, which is awesome.